# Write data to an external file in Java

Tags: java, file, url, io, bufferedreader

I have data in my BufferedReader, but I want to print the data in an external file.
How do I do that?

```
    URL url=new URL(input);
    BufferedReader br=new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(url.openStream()));
    String inputLine;
    while((inputLine=br.readLine())!=null)
        System.out.println(inputLine);
    br.close();
```

The above code works for me. Instead, I want to save the data in an external file.

Answer (score 0):

```
URL url=new URL(input);
BufferedReader br=new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(url.openStream()));
String inputLine;
BufferedWriter writer = Files.newBufferedWriter(Paths.get(""));
while ((inputLine = br.readLine()) != null) {
   System.out.println(inputLine);
   writer.write(inputLine);
   // must do this: .readLine() will have stripped line endings
   writer.newLine();
   }
writer.close();
br.close();
```

Answer (score 0):

If i have understood correctly you have your data and you want to write them in an external txt file.

```
  String path1 = "Your Path File";
  File file1 = new File(path1);
  file1.createNewFile();
  FileWriter fw = new FileWriter(file1);
  BufferedWriter bw = new BufferedWriter(fw); 
  bw.write("\n"+ your data); // "\n" because the new data will overwrite the previous 
                             //and it will be lost
  bw.flush();
  FileReader fr = new FileReader(file1);
  BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(fr);

    br.close();
    bw.close();
```